# How can I host multiple websites from one port with IIS?

Tags: iis, virtualhost, dns-hosting

i install DNS Server on windows server 2008 r2 and install IIS on it.

i want to know how can i configure my dns records to show sites to my users .it is an external dns server and i want to install many sites on it's iis , when user call for example www.test1.com show site1 on port 8085 and when request test2.com show site2 on port 8090

but like host centers i do not want user enter port number at the request like test1:8085.com

or somethings like this

how can i handle my dns server and iis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is how to set up something known as a [name-based virtual host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based). This is a feature where a webserver examines the *HTTP/1.1 HOST header* supplied in a web browser's request and uses this to determine what website is being requested.

None of these websites would need their own unique ports configured (unless special circumstances arise): they can all share port 80.

While it would be possible for someone who knows `IIS` better than me to guide you through this process, I think it would be best to steer you toward seeking some self-education on the topic of web hosting. Name-based virtual hosts are considered fairly basic knowledge in professional hosting environments, and you are going to run into many problems trying to set up working configurations if you have not been exposed to the names of concepts like this one. It's hard to search for help on Google otherwise, nevermind this website. :)

We're here to help you with technical problems that you run into along the way, but it'll be a very slow and inefficient process to help you every time something like this pops up.